# Mobile development in unity3d - increase android fps number

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I create an unity3d scene. It has a model that is 245.487 KB. It runs with **only 3 fps** on TF300TG Asus Tablet.

- I remove all lines includes `Debug.Log`
- Camera clear flag is solid color
- Vsysnc is set "Every VBlank"

It runs with 60-80 fps on my pc. How can I increase android fps number?

My scene has a Canvas. And the scene creates some button in `OnGUI()` function.

**EDIT**

I remove canvas and OnGUI function. My scene has only .obj model. The app's fps is 4 on android, but editor is 50.

Comment: 3fps is bad. really really bad. This is one of the things where you must know how detect and solve your own problem because without your game code and 3D models, we can't tell what's happening. Use the profiler to find out what's taking so long in in your app. Refactor all code that allocates memory.

Comment: Is 245.487 KB large amount for android?

Comment: That's fine. I am talking about 3fps. The lowest should be 15. Anything less is unacceptable. Also you mentioned you used OnGUI(). That's a big no no. Use the new Unity UI. You have to start from scratch.  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: @Programmer ,  Why big no to OnGUI()?

Comment: @paulp I have a feeling you use `OnGUI` too. It should be used for debugging and not for your game UI then comment out if building your game. You get spikes with it. Draw call is too much. GUI stuff instead the  `OnGUI` allocates memory. Some say this is false but last time I used it, it was true. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html

Comment: @Programmer Yeah I use OnGUI to show items in the List and get sudden spikes in profiler with it , DO you know any alternative to OnGUI  ?

Comment: @paulp I provided a link in the first comment I made. It is called uGUI and every UI should be under the Canvas.  Tutorials https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: On profiler, Camera.Renderer use most time in cpu. My model has many subobjects and they have multiple materials.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check if the Unity demos run ok on your device. 
2) Check what all processing happens when you render each frame. Try to find the bottleneck - example is computations, database queries, disk read writes. Then check if this can be optimized by storing required data in memory etc.
3) Try reducing number of draw operations on your canvas to see if it affects speed.

Comment: I remove canvas and OnGUI function. My scene has only .obj model. The app's fps is 4 on android, but editor is 50..